# how to find the bit on the right in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to identify if a number is even or odd, and I think that this could be achieved just taking the bit on the left of that number for example:

```
number    bit      odd
  1       0001      1
  2       0010      0
  3       0011      1
  4       0100      0
```

So if the last bit is 1 then it is odd and if it is 0 then it is even.

How can I solve this on python? using bitwise operations of course, like the title, I just want to get the last bit of the number.

Thank you.

Comment: This kind of low-level hackery is not encouraged in the Python world - it's harder to read, and probably won't actually gain you much.

Comment: true, but nonetheless an interesting question, don't you mean?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the question, I would just advise against ever actually using this.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote? if this was too easy, I apologyze, but I couldn't find the answer on google, so I asked here.

Comment: @eLRuLL the people on SO generally downvote anything that could possibly be efficient. Please solve this problem with strings ;)

Comment: @harold aren't bitwise operations better?

Comment: @eLRuLL of course they are, that's the problem. Way too good. Any minute now someone will get in here and drop a "no one knows what bitwise AND does and therefore we shouldn't use it"-bomb, oh wait, they already sort of have. "advise against ever actually using this"? Yea this is the most complex piece of code ever, surely no one will understand it.. god forbid programmers actually learn to program. Just ignore me by the way, I'm just complaining about the mentality around here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bitwise-and `&`:

```
odd = number & 1
```

---

```
In [24]: for number in range(1, 5):
   ....:     print(number & 1)
   ....:     
   ....:     
1
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use the modulo operator for such a task:

```
1 % 2 # gives you 1 (odd)
2 % 2 # gives you 0 (even)
```

Answer (score 0):

TO check if a number is even or odd, just use

```
if a%2:
    #do stuff
 else:
     #do stuff
```

Comment: is %(mod) bitwise operator?

Comment: or you can also use the method suggested above. `if number&1`